# Eclipse XML Validation - how to exclude certain files?

Tags: eclipse, validation, eclipse-wtp

Since the reactions in the Eclipse WTP forum were not really helpful I try to maybe get an answer here:

In our test folders we have a couple of (purposely) faulty XML files.
EACH and EVERY time I do a full rebuild these are flagged as validation errors!

No matter what I specify in Preferences -> Validation -> XML Validation -> Settings under "Exclude Group: these files keep getting validated and hence flagged as build errors and this is mighty annoying!

What syntax is expected for a "Folder or Filename" rule?

Our faulty testfiles are named like "Filename-01.xml" to "Filename-30.xml" but strings like "Filename*.xml" or "Filename*" (with or without the case sensitive flag checked) obviously don't match. Whether specifying the full pathname or just the directory-local name or even trying with RegEx syntax (i.e. "Filename.*") didn't make any difference.

What is the secret sauce to get this "Exclude Group" working? 
Or is this simply a bug that we have to live with (because I have little hope that this will ever get fixed...)?

Comment: What makes you think that wildcards are supported there? Most of the bugs I have reported to Eclipse have been fixed (especially those with a patch)?

Comment: @howlger Hm - you might be right! The dialog does indeed nowhere state that the name is considered as "pattern". I guess the term "Exclusion group" made me immediately think that one can exclude entire "groups" of files and hence that the name entered would be taken as pattern. But maybe one actually has to list each and every file individually. Tedious but I will give it a try. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Unfortunately no joy! Specifying an entire list of files to be excluded, neither just entering the filename nor specifying the entire path, prevents the XML-Validator from validating these files during a "full build". :-(  Guess I need to file a bug here...